# In Excel 2010, how can I subtract two times when I also have the date in the cell and get the value in seconds?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, timestamp

I have a column of data as follows:

```
 09/22/2015 10:25:22
 09/22/2015 10:27:00
```

I want to subtract `09/22/2015 10:27:00` from `09/22/2015 10:25:22` to get the value of `98` seconds.

I tried formatting the cells to the form `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and then subtracting them, but it didn't work.

Can I get the differences without removing the date and creating a separate column containing data in the format `hh:mm:ss` ?

Comment: `A2-A1` works for me with your values exactly as shown.  It gives a result of 0.00113426, which is 98 seconds expressed in days.  (0.00113426*60*60*24=98)

Comment: These differences are likely a result of date format settings (localization settings) on the machines in question. I

Comment: Adam, is it possible for you to provide the format settings that you used? Especially the format setting of the two cells where you put in the times and the out output cell?

Comment: Achyutha, can you find out whether Excel is interpreting your column of data as strings?

Comment: If Excel recognizes the input as a date/time, it gets stored in the form of a number representing the number of days since a reference date plus the decimal fraction of a day that the time is equivalent to.  How you display it is irrelevant, and there are built in formats to display the entire date/time or pieces of it in a variety of ways.  The units of the stored number is days.  You can do straight math on this as you would any other number, even subtracting one from the other when the formats are different or you aren't even displaying the time units being subtracted.  (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) The result is still stored in units of days, and you can format it to display as you want.  The canned formats are designed around clock time, so if you display seconds, you might get 38 because a clock would display it as 1 minute 38 seconds.  If there isn't a canned format that works the way you want, just do the math yourself.  As Jamie Hanrahan describes, there are 86,400 seconds in a day, so if you multiply the result in day units by 86,400, you convert it to seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `[ss]` custom format for the resulting cell

If your source cells with have General format (i.e Text, not DateTime) , then please use `=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A2,8))-TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))`
instead of `=A2-A1`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is the format of the cells `A1` and `A2`?

Comment: The standard time format. Actually the format doesn't matter here.

Comment: Alex, here is the issue with your answer which I am facing: 

If I type in the data `09/22/2015` excel is automatically converting it to a custom format of `m/d/yyyy h:mm`. And I can do the subtraction as required. However, since my data is already being downloaded from an external source, data in the column is in the 'General' format. If I change this to `m/d/yyyy h:mm` and then calculate the difference in a cell of `[ss]` format, the error still appears. I am not sure how you can simulate this on your sheet.

Comment: Achyutha, I have just updated my answer, please see above.

Answer (score 3):

The result of subtracting one date from another, as with all date arithmetic in Excel, is a number wherein each "1" is one day.

There are 86,400 seconds in a day, so the difference in your case would be 98/86400. If you format it as a number that's what you'll get. If you multiply that number by 86,400 you'll have the difference in seconds. (You may have to format it as a "number" for it to display properly.)  If instead of multiplying by 86,400 you format it as a time, you will get the difference displayed in time format (hh:mm:ss), which could be useful if you expect large differences.

Now... when I tried your exact example on my machine the result of the calculation is an error message, "#VALUE!" Excel seems not to be recognizing them as date-and-times in that form, probably because that form is ambiguous for day numbers 12 and below. It seems to be storing it as a simple string. But if I type the date part as yyyy-mm-dd it works fine. dd-Month-yyyy (as in 23-Sep-2015) also works. So does "Jan 4, 2015".

On the other hand, another answer says that the date format you used does work for them. These differences are likely a result of date format settings (localization settings) on the machines in question. You may have to compromise a bit on your date entry format, or write a formula that interprets the date-as-string and turns it into a date Excel can use.

Try this: Assuming your date1 and date2 are in columns A and B... create column C with the formula `=datevalue(A1)` and column D with `=datevalue(B1)` . Then your subtraction (in column E) subtracts C1 from D1.

In any case, removing the date part is not necessary.